# Windows Terminal Server Access Denied after enabling SMBv1/CIFS role

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, server-message-block, windows-terminal-services

I've just took over the one network and there is a terminal server 2012. The users faced an issue that they can't connect to the older shared folder(or even map them as network drive), so I've asked previous admin - did he know something about it and he said that he could, probably, accidentally or manually, disable the SMBv1.

After reading tons of manuals - I've found out that you can enable the SMBv1 suopport through the Roles. I've performed this and , as I was asked, went in reboot. After the reboot - I can't connect to the terminal with the Domain Admin account. It says that "Access Denied", then I've tried to enter as the freshly created domain admin and received that "An attempt was made to logon, but the network logon service hasn't been started"...

I feel that tomorrow I'll get killed, but anyway - is there any solution for this? Because there is two errors and I can't understand how this can go with SMBv1/CIFS ...

Comment: `An attempt was made to logon, but the network logon service hasn't been started` - Did you check the Netlogon service to make sure it's running?

Comment: I even can't connect with RDP anymore. Will try the local today...

Comment: So, the solution was found. Actually, this was a mega-super-stupid typo while I was enabling the SMBv1 through the cmd. So, I've asked the lanman to depend on bRowser, not bowser and then I'v found out that , thanks to my typo, the lanman depends on browser and browser depends on lanman and they both can't be started. I've googled quickly and found that I'm not the only stupid around there and that it should depend on bowser, so I've changed, rebooted and netlogon service started successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was found. Actually, this was a mega-super-stupid typo while I was enabling the SMBv1 through the cmd. So, I've asked the lanman to depend on bRowser, not bowser and then I'v found out that , thanks to my typo, the lanman depends on browser and browser depends on lanman and they both can't be started. I've googled quickly and found that I'm not the only stupid around there and that it should depend on bowser, so I've changed, rebooted and netlogon service started successfully.